# strange behaviour for azure blob

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

i am using azure-storage to read blob files from container in my nodejs code

My code

```
blobService.listBlobsSegmented(containerName, token, { maxResults : 10 }, function(err, result) {

    if (err) {
        console.log("Couldn't list blobs for container %s", containerName);
        console.error(err);

    } else {
        // do things here
    }

});
```

It is working fine but when increase blob limit 10 to 500 my network stop working. what can be issue here ?

Comment: What do you  mean by `my network stop working`? What's the Internet speed?

Comment: yes the google.com shows me site not found page. event i tired to ping the other site and it fails.Site down or blocked

google.com is down or blocked.

Check your internet connection and retry
Retry
Access

Comment: I think there's an issue with your network connection.

Comment: I tested it couple of time its only happen when i increase maxResults to 500 or more

Comment: Is there any piping for request as i am also inserting blob data to the database table (using Promise)

Comment: Honestly, how would we know if inserting the blob data in table is causing problem for you?

Comment: i also tried after removing insertion code from my file and still same issue

Answer (score 0):

If you do an HTTP traffic capture with network analyzers like Fiddler or Wireshark, you will find this SDK ([azure-storage](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node)) is just a REST API wrapper. So, it doesn't have much control on the network. If you still have this problem, I would recommend you check your computer or router network settings.

[image]